# vb.net arcobjects spatial query get fields value of desired layer only

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, spatial-query

Currently I am using ArcObjects (10.2.1) in vb.net (vs 2012). What I intent to develop is a spatial query tool. There are 2 steps in the function:

(1) Use "Select Features" tool in ArcMap to select features in a certain area.

(2) List the several fields of features selected of a layer.

My question is how to get the field values only for a desired feature layer. My code is listed  below. It only works when only the desired layer is enabled on ArcMap.

```vb
    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
    Dim pMap As IMap
    Dim pEnumFeature As IEnumFeature
    Dim pEnumFeatureSetup As IEnumFeatureSetup
    Dim pFeature As IFeature

    pMxDoc = My.ArcMap.Document
    pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap
    pEnumFeature = pMap.FeatureSelection
    pEnumFeatureSetup = pEnumFeature
    pEnumFeatureSetup.AllFields = True
    pFeature = pEnumFeature.Next

    Dim layerNum = GetIndexNumberFromLayerName(pActiveView, "testdb.DBO.testTable")
    pFeatSel = pMap.Layer(layerNum)

    Dim tempArr As New List(Of String)
    Do While (Not pFeature Is Nothing)
        tempArr.Add(pFeature.Value(pFeature.Fields.FindField("Item_ID")).ToString)
        pFeature = pEnumFeature.Next
    Loop

    Dim message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, tempArr.ToArray())
    Dim lstOfString As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(tempArr)
    Dim selectedCount = lstOfString.Count

    End If


Public Function GetIndexNumberFromLayerName(ByVal activeView As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView, ByVal layerName As System.String) As System.Int32

    If activeView Is Nothing OrElse layerName Is Nothing Then
        Return -1
    End If

    Dim map As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMap = activeView.FocusMap
    Dim numberOfLayers As System.Int32 = map.LayerCount
    Dim i As System.Int32 = 0
    Do While i < numberOfLayers
        If layerName = map.Layer(i).Name Then
            Return i
        End If
        i += 1
    Loop
    Return -1
    LayerNumber = i
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are making this more difficult than it has to be. You are obtaining your selected features from IMap.FeatureSelection. So multiple layers could return a selection.

A much better way is to get a handle on your *ILayer*, cast that into an *IFeatureLayer* then point an *IFeatureSelection* interface to *IFeatureLayer*. From this you can get an *ISelectionSet*. This has a Search method which returns a cursor over the selection in that specific layer.

Here is a bit of sample code:

```vb
Dim pFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection
pFeatureSelection = pFeatureLayer

Dim pSelectionSet As ISelectionSet
pSelectionSet = pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet

Dim pFeatureCursor As IFeatureCursor = Nothing
pSelectionSet.Search(Nothing, True, pFeatureCursor)
```

Comment: Hi Hornbydd, thanks a lot for the quick advice. Will try to follow the workflow you suggested.

Comment: Hi Hornbydd, your sample code helps me to select features in the desired layer successfully, but I failed to get the field value of the selected feature, I put my updated code below. To make the code clear, I put it as an answer. Appreciate if you can have a look, many tanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fully working code:

```vb
    pMxDoc = My.ArcMap.Application.Document
    pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap
    pActiveView = pMxDoc.FocusMap

    Dim layerNum = GetIndexNumberFromLayerName(pActiveView, "testdb.DBO.testTable")
    Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
    pFeatureLayer = pMap.Layer(layerNum)

    Dim pFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection
    pFeatureSelection = pFeatureLayer

    Dim pSelectionSet As ISelectionSet
    pSelectionSet = pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet

    Dim pFeatureCursor As IFeatureCursor = Nothing
    pSelectionSet.Search(Nothing, True, pFeatureCursor)

    Dim tempArr As New List(Of String)

    Dim pFeature As IFeature
    pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
    Do While (Not pFeature Is Nothing)
        tempArr.Add(pFeature.Value(pFeature.Fields.FindField("Item_ID")).ToString)
        pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
    Loop
```

Comment: I have edited your reply to show you how the code should be.

Comment: Hi Hornbydd, thanks you very much for your help. But the map still crash when executing the line pFeature = pFeatureCursor.Next before looping.

Comment: Hi Hornbydd, it works after I modified the line pFeature = pFeatureCursor.Next to pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Hi Andre Silva, I just use the code in above except change pFeatureCursor.Next to pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature

Comment: Yes I change both lines.

Comment: Hi Andre, in my case, when I add pFeatureCursor. and list down all functions, the available functions include NextFeature, but no Next. If I use pFeatureCursor.Next, no compile error but runtime error.